# How to get the tab object in react native code

Tags: react-native

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <TextInput style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
               onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
               value={this.state.text}/>
    <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='white' onPress={onPressButton}>
        <Image style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
               source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}
        />
    </TouchableHighlight>
</View>
```

I want to get the View, like in html use the 'getElementById()', but in React native, How do I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `ref`:

```
<View ref={(ref) => {this._myView = ref}} />
```

Then in your code you can access the `View` like this:

```
this._myView  // Do whatever you need here
```

Docs here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#the-ref-callback-attribute

Comment: React Native uses React under the hood. The docs for React are completely valid and useful.

Comment: I know, but I didn't succeed,use the method

Comment: What do you mean with _didn't succeed, use the method_?

Comment: Keep in mind that the callback will be triggered when the reference is ready, that means when the component is mounted. If you try to access it before, it will be `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you very much